# Applying aphaser ffmpeg filter cuts audio - android

Tags: android, audio, filter, ffmpeg

Hi Im applying ffmpeg audio filters (aphaser) using following command:
`cmd = "-y -i " + currentRecordedFilePath + " -af aphaser=0.8:1.0:1.0:0.8:1.0:s " + outputFilePath;`

it does apply effect but the output file duration is lesser than input, like it cuts the audio towards the end. why is it happening?

Thanks.

console output:

```
05-18 15:01:59.633 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onStart: onStart
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
05-18 15:02:00.123 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
05-18 15:02:00.153 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/com.test.soundapp/files/131_18052017150137.m4a':
05-18 15:02:00.153 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   Metadata:
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     major_brand     : mp42
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     minor_version   : 0
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     compatible_brands: isommp42
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     creation_time   : 2017-05-18 10:01:59
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     com.android.version: 6.0.1
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:21.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 24000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     Metadata:
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:       creation_time   : 2017-05-18 10:01:59
05-18 15:02:00.163 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
05-18 15:02:00.173 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: [Parsed_aphaser_0 @ 0xb5c200f0] in_gain may cause clipping
05-18 15:02:00.173 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: [Parsed_aphaser_0 @ 0xb5c200f0] out_gain may cause clipping
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: Output #0, ipod, to '/data/user/0/com.test.soundapp/files/131_18052017150137.m4a':
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   Metadata:
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     major_brand     : mp42
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     minor_version   : 0
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     compatible_brands: isommp42
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     com.android.version: 6.0.1
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 16 kb/s (default)
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:     Metadata:
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:       creation_time   : 2017-05-18 10:01:59
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: Stream mapping:
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
05-18 15:02:00.323 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
05-18 15:02:00.893 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: size=       6kB time=00:00:02.81 bitrate=  17.2kbits/s speed= 5.4x    
05-18 15:02:01.363 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: size=      11kB time=00:00:05.31 bitrate=  16.6kbits/s speed=5.18x    
05-18 15:02:01.623 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: [aac @ 0xb5c03c00] Input buffer exhausted before END element found
05-18 15:02:01.623 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
05-18 15:02:01.623 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xb5c1a000] stream 0, offset 0x807e: partial file
05-18 15:02:01.623 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: /data/user/0/com.test.soundapp/files/131_18052017150137.m4a: Invalid data found when processing input
05-18 15:02:01.643 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: size=      17kB time=00:00:08.12 bitrate=  17.6kbits/s speed=6.14x    
05-18 15:02:01.643 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: video:0kB audio:16kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 7.609221%
05-18 15:02:01.643 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onProgress: [aac @ 0xb5c03400] Qavg: 243.772
05-18 15:02:01.643 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/SUCCESS: SUCCESS
05-18 15:02:01.653 2668-2668/com.test.soundapp E/onFinish: onFinis
```

h

Comment: Need to see full command and console output.

Comment: Audio is malformed: `[aac @ 0xb5c03c00] Input buffer exhausted before END element found
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: @Mulvya Ohh, makes sense .. but sir how to fix this? is my audio input (recorded) wrong? its settings are `mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(24000);` 
`mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(32000);`
`mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);`
`mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC);`

Comment: Those settings aren't an issue. The bitstream it's writing is malformed, or atleast ffmpeg's AAC parser can't handle it. Try another codec.

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks for the explanation. Mulvya I'm fairly new to ffmpeg, by codec you mean apply another audio filter?

Comment: No, record your audio with another codec. You can convert to HE-AAC with ffmpeg if you have libfdk_aac enabled.